# Elasticsearch Nest 2.x index nested object

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I'm new in Elasticsearch and Nest and blocked in a problem. What I want to do is create a index and index a doc with nested fields.

```
    [ElasticsearchType]
public class TestType
{
    [Nest.String(Store = true, Index = FieldIndexOption.Analyzed )]
    public string  Text { get; set; }

    [Nested(IncludeInAll = true)]
    public List<NestedTestType> Nests { get; set; } = new List<NestedTestType>();

    public string Id { get; set; }      
}

[ElasticsearchType]
public class NestedTestType
{
    [Nest.String(Store = true, Index = FieldIndexOption.Analyzed)]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    [Nest.String(Store = false)]
    public string NotStoredValue { get; set; }
}
```

and in the function it is

```
            var connectionPool = new Elasticsearch.Net.SniffingConnectionPool(poolUris);
        var settings = new ConnectionSettings(connectionPool);
        client = new ElasticClient(settings);

        string testIndexName = "test";
        var createIndeReponse = client.CreateIndex(testIndexName);
        var mappingResponse = client.Map<TestType>(m => m.Index(testIndexName).AutoMap());
       mappingResponse = client.Map<NestedTestType>(m => m.Index(testIndexName).AutoMap());

        TestType testData = new TestType() { Text = "Hello world" };
        testData.Nests.Add( new NestedTestType() { Value = "In the list", NotStoredValue = "Not stored"} );

        IndexRequest<TestType> indexRequest = new IndexRequest<TestType>(testIndexName, "test_type");
        indexRequest.Document = testData;
        IIndexResponse iir = client.Index(indexRequest);
```

However, the iir in the last line contains an error "object mapping [nests] can't be changed from nested to non-nested"

My questions are :

What is the correct way to do the indexing? 
Where can I find documentation which will help me further?

Comment: May you share your index mapping(http://localhost:9200/test/_mapping)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few observations:

- The type names for both `TestType` and `NestedTestType` will be inferred from the CLR type name. By default, these will be the camel cased version of the type name i.e. `testType` and `nestedTestType`, respectively.
- Since `NestedTestType` is a nested type on `TestType`, you don't need to add a mapping separately for it in the index; the mapping of `NestedTestType` is part of the mapping of `TestType`
- You don't specify a value for the `Id` of `TestType`; [NEST will infer the id of the document from the `Id` property](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/ids-inference.html#_inferring_from_a_type) which will be null; Elasticsearch will be fine with this and generate a unique id for the document, storing it in the `_id` field, but this unique id will not be set against the `Id` property in `_source` meaning there would be no easy way of retrieving this document by id using NEST conventions. I'd recommend setting a value for `Id` and also mapping the field as `not_analyzed`

The reason for the error is that when indexing `TestType`, you specify the type name to be `test_type` as opposed to explicitly specifying `testType` or just letting NEST infer it for you.

When Elasticsearch sees the json document coming in, it doesn't associate it with the mapping for `TestType` that was created earlier since the type names don't match (`testType` vs. `test_type`) so attempts to map `nests` as an object. ***But***, the index does contain a nested mapping already for objects under the path `nests`, which is giving rise to the error.

To solve, we can do

```
var connectionPool = new Elasticsearch.Net.SniffingConnectionPool(poolUris);
string testIndexName = "test";

var settings = new ConnectionSettings(connectionPool)
    // specify test to be the default index, meaning if no index name
    // is explicitly passed to a request or inferred from the type,
    // this will be the default
    .DefaultIndex(testIndexName);

var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

// create the index and add the mapping at the same time
var createIndeReponse = client.CreateIndex(testIndexName, c => c
    .Mappings(m => m
        .Map<TestType>(mm => mm.AutoMap())
    )
);

TestType testData = new TestType { Text = "Hello world", Id = "1" };
testData.Nests.Add(new NestedTestType { Value = "In the list", NotStoredValue = "Not stored" });

IIndexResponse iir = client.Index(testData);
```

If you want to specify that `TestType` should be mapped as the type name `test_type`, you can use `MapDefaultTypeNames` on connection settings

```
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(connectionPool)
    .DefaultIndex(testIndexName)
    .MapDefaultTypeNames(d => d
        .Add(typeof(TestType), "test_type")
    );
```